# How do I put a black opaque background behind a UI tableview?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a `textfield` that, when text is entered, pops up into a `tableview`. The `tableview` only takes up the bottom half of the screen, and when the `tableview` is showing at least one option, I would like to make the rest of the screen an opaque black. (Note, I’m not talking about the color of the `tableview` itself, but adding a dark tint to the rest of the screen.) The area on top of the `tableview` also has other elements, so it’s not as simple as just changing the background color. Whenever I try to change it from where the `tableview` is controlled, I end up just changing the background of the `tableview` itself.

Here is a visual of something similar to what I’m trying to achieve:

https://images.app.goo.gl/npAE5ga2kCmQ8E2d7 .

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You would need to add a “dimming view”.

Answer (score 0):

**1)** Add your Selection  options in new viewController names as optionPopUp(what ever you want).

**2)** set modalpresntationstyle of  your new popUp as **over current context** with transition style as crossdisolve.

**3)** set background view color of new popUp viewcontroller with opacity(0.1 or 10%).

**4)**Present you popUp from source view controller i.e in didselectrowat method of uitableview delegate

Comment: Can you elaborate on the 4th step? In the didselectrow for the tableview. It would be something like .present(optionPopUp)? What is it being presented from?

Comment: yes . it would be like self.present(optionPopUp, animated: true/false, completion: nil). Preset PopUp from anywhere you want to use.Make sure you have created intence of optionPopUp before presenting.

Comment: Okay thanks. This code would go in viewdidload right? optionPopUp.modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext
        optionPopUp.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.black

Comment: No above the code from where you are presenting your optionPopUp after creating the instence . you can set background color in viewdidload of popUp with opacity from 0 to 1(according to your need).